# Creating a count per hour in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make a report that uses course schedules to count how many students are unavailable in a given hour. So if a student has a class from 8:00 to 9:15 am I want them to be counted as unavailable for the 8:00 - 9:00 time block and 9:00 - 10:00 time block. I am using SQL to write this report.

I believe I will need a case statement that builds in the logic of if the start time is equal to or greater than 8:00 and the end time is greater than 8:00 then count + 1 but I am unsure of how to create this case statement for classes that are over an hour such as some classes that go from 7:30 - 15:30.
Note: I am wanting to build this into a bar graph so the output of the case statement will need to be legible to a chart.

Here is an example of the data I am using to create this report.
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Ckl.jpg)

```
select SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM "PIDM",
       SSRMEET.SSRMEET_SUN_DAY,
       SSRMEET.SSRMEET_MON_DAY,
       SSRMEET.SSRMEET_TUE_DAY,
       SSRMEET.SSRMEET_WED_DAY,
       SSRMEET.SSRMEET_THU_DAY,
       SSRMEET.SSRMEET_FRI_DAY,
       SSRMEET.SSRMEET_SAT_DAY,
       SSRMEET.SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME,
       SSRMEET.SSRMEET_END_TIME
  from SATURN.SGBSTDN SGBSTDN,
       SATURN.SFRSTCR SFRSTCR,
       SATURN.SSRMEET SSRMEET,
       SATURN.SSBSECT SSBSECT,
       SATURN.SGRSPRT SGRSPRT
 where ( SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PIDM
         and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
         and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN
         and SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SGRSPRT.SGRSPRT_PIDM
         and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SGRSPRT.SGRSPRT_TERM_CODE
         and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE = SSRMEET.SSRMEET_TERM_CODE
         and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN = SSRMEET.SSRMEET_CRN)
   and ( SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '202330'
         and SGRSPRT.SGRSPRT_ACTC_CODE = 'NCAASB'
         --and :main_btn_RunQuery is not null
         and SGRSPRT.SGRSPRT_ELIG_CODE = 'Y'
         and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE || SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB || SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB not like 'ES0%'
         and SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF =
         ( select Max( N1.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF ) "Max_SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF"
             from SATURN.SGBSTDN N1
            where N1.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM ) )
order by    SSRMEET.SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can recreate the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Lastly, don't post any images as they cant be cut and pasted.

Comment: Your data would probably be easier to work with if it was standardized  as DayOfWeek, MeetBegin, MeetEnd.  Start by selecting the hours 0-23 as a result, then left join every record, and sum every record where the hour overlaps.

Comment: I agree the data would be much easier to work with if we had a DayOfWeek field, we have a Days_Code that is supposed to hold that data but has not been populated by our registrar. I am new to the company so I am unable to make those changes which is why my first idea is to create a case statement to filter down the data. As I got started I quickly realized this is a pretty intense case statement.
The procedure I am trying to mimic uses an array for everyday of the week to hold a value for each hour which makes the procedure very long and bulky.

Comment: You could select all records where meeting on Sunday, UNION ALL with records where meeting on Monday, etc.  Then group by both meeting day and hour as below if you wanted results for every day.

Comment: @Pugzly Sorry but if I include the SQL I have written it wouldn't do much good as it is using company-specific tables and fields and if I wanted to show my code it would have to be a picture due to the character limit of stack overflow. Do you have any recommendations of what I can do to give you a better idea of my problem?

Comment: @Seth Of course you can give us code; you make up something that is similar to the actual problem using non-proprietary code.

Comment: Thank you to everyone that's helped so far. I have added my code for the sample data to help explain where I'm pulling the data from and how I'm pulling the data. I'm sorry that I did not originally include that, I am only 3 months into my data analytics career and still very new to this type of data processing. I really appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full code used to answer my original question of creating a count for each hour-long time block in a given day using course schedule data.
First I had to use a case statement that would separate the start and end times of each course into hour-long time blocks. Then I used an NVL(SUM..) statement to count the number of students in each time block.
Once I had that data I used an unpivot function to make variables HOUR_COUNTS and HOUR_CODE to be used when graphing the data.

```
WITH TEMP_ATH_SCHEDULE AS
(SELECT ATHL_CRSE_CONF.GROUP_DAY_OF_WEEK,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."1"), 0) AS Hour01,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."2"), 0) AS Hour02,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."3"), 0) AS Hour03,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."4"), 0) AS Hour04,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."5"), 0) AS Hour05,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."6"), 0) AS Hour06,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."7"), 0) AS Hour07,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."8"), 0) AS Hour08,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."9"), 0) AS Hour09,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."10"), 0) AS Hour10,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."11"), 0) AS Hour11,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."12"), 0) AS Hour12,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."13"), 0) AS Hour13,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."14"), 0) AS Hour14,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."15"), 0) AS Hour15,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."16"), 0) AS Hour16,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."17"), 0) AS Hour17,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."18"), 0) AS Hour18,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."19"), 0) AS Hour19,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."20"), 0) AS Hour20,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."21"), 0) AS Hour21,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."22"), 0) AS Hour22,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."23"), 0) AS Hour23,
             NVL(SUM(ATHL_CRSE_CONF."0"), 0) AS Hour00
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0000', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0000', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0059', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0000', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0059', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "0",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0100', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0100', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0159', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0100', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0159', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "1",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0200', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0200', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0259', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0200', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0259', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "2",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0300', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0300', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0359', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0300', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0359', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "3",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0400', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0400', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0459', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0400', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0459', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "4",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0500', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0500', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0559', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0500', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0559', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "5",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0600', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0600', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0659', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0600', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0659', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "6",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0700', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0700', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0759', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0700', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0759', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "7",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0800', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0800', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0859', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0800', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0859', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "8",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0900', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0900', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0959', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0900', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('0959', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "9",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1000', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1000', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1059', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1000', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1059', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "10",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1100', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1100', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1159', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1100', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1159', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "11",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1200', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1200', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1259', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1200', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1259', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "12",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1300', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1300', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1359', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1300', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1359', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "13",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1400', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1400', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1459', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1400', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1459', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "14",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1500', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1500', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1559', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1500', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1559', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "15",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1600', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1600', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1659', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1600', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1659', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "16",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1700', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1700', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1759', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1700', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1759', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "17",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1800', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1800', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1859', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1800', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1859', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "18",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1900', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1900', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1959', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1900', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1959', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "19",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2000', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2000', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2059', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2000', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2059', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "20",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2100', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2100', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2159', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2100', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2159', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "21",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2200', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2200', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2259', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2200', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2259', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "22",
                      CASE
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2300', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') BETWEEN
                             SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME AND SSRMEET_END_TIME) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2300', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2359', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                        WHEN (SSRMEET_END_TIME BETWEEN
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2300', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi') AND
                             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2359', 'hh24mi'), 'hh24mi')) THEN
                         '1'
                      END AS "23",
                      NVL(SSRMEET_SUN_DAY, '') U,
                      NVL(SSRMEET_MON_DAY, '') M,
                      NVL(SSRMEET_TUE_DAY, '') T,
                      NVL(SSRMEET_WED_DAY, '') W,
                      NVL(SSRMEET_THU_DAY, '') R,
                      NVL(SSRMEET_FRI_DAY, '') F,
                      NVL(SSRMEET_SAT_DAY, '') S,
                      DAY_DESC GROUP_DAY_OF_WEEK,
                      SFR.SFRSTCR_PIDM PIDM

      FROM SPRIDEN SPR_INSTRUCTOR,
           SIRASGN SIR,
           SSRMEET SSR,
           (SELECT 'U' DAY_CODE, 'SUNDAY' DAY_DESC
            FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'M', 'MONDAY'
            FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'T', 'TUESDAY'
            FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'W', 'WEDNESDAY'
            FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'R', 'THURSDAY'
            FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'F', 'FRIDAY'
            FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'S', 'SATURDAY'
            FROM DUAL) DAY_OF_WEEK,
           SFRSTCR SFR,
           SCBCRSE SCB,
           SSBSECT SSB
      WHERE SFR.SFRSTCR_PIDM IN
            (SELECT S1.SGRSPRT_PIDM
             FROM SGRSPRT S1, SGRATHC SGR
             WHERE S1.SGRSPRT_TERM_CODE LIKE
                   '%' || SUBSTR(:parm_DD_TermCodes.CODE, 0, 4) || '%'
             AND SGR.SGRATHC_PIDM(+) = S1.SGRSPRT_PIDM
             AND SGR.SGRATHC_TERM_CODE(+) = S1.SGRSPRT_TERM_CODE
             AND SGR.SGRATHC_ACTC_CODE(+) = S1.SGRSPRT_ACTC_CODE
             AND S1.SGRSPRT_SPST_CODE = 'AC'
             AND ((S1.SGRSPRT_ELIG_CODE = 'Y' AND S1.SGRSPRT_SAEL_CODE = 'EL' AND
                   EXISTS
                    (SELECT 'Y'
                     FROM SGRATHC SGR1
                     WHERE SGR1.SGRATHC_PIDM = SGR.SGRATHC_PIDM
                     AND SGR1.SGRATHC_SEASON_USED_IND = 'Y'
                     AND SGR1.SGRATHC_ACTIVITY_DATE =
                           (SELECT MAX(SGR2.SGRATHC_ACTIVITY_DATE)
                            FROM SGRATHC SGR2
                            WHERE SGR2.SGRATHC_PIDM = SGR1.SGRATHC_PIDM
                            AND SGR2.SGRATHC_TERM_CODE = SGR1.SGRATHC_TERM_CODE
                            AND SGR2.SGRATHC_ACTC_CODE = SGR1.SGRATHC_ACTC_CODE)
                     AND SGR1.SGRATHC_TERM_CODE IN
                           (SELECT T3.STVTERM_CODE
                            FROM STVTERM T3
                            WHERE T3.STVTERM_TRMT_CODE = 'S'
                            AND T3.STVTERM_CODE LIKE '%' || SUBSTR(:parm_DD_TermCodes.CODE, 0, 4) || '%'))))
             AND S1.SGRSPRT_ACTC_CODE = :main_DD_Sport_Type.SPRT_CODE
             AND S1.SGRSPRT_ACTIVITY_DATE =
                   (SELECT MAX(S4.SGRSPRT_ACTIVITY_DATE)
                    FROM SGRSPRT S4
                    WHERE S4.SGRSPRT_PIDM = S1.SGRSPRT_PIDM
                    AND S4.SGRSPRT_TERM_CODE = S1.SGRSPRT_TERM_CODE
                    AND S4.SGRSPRT_ACTC_CODE = S1.SGRSPRT_ACTC_CODE))
      AND SFR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = :parm_DD_TermCodes.CODE
      AND SFR.SFRSTCR_CRN IN
            (SELECT SFR1.SFRSTCR_CRN AS CRN
             FROM STVTERM STV1, SFRSTCR SFR1
             WHERE SFR1.SFRSTCR_PIDM = SFR.SFRSTCR_PIDM
             AND STV1.STVTERM_CODE = :parm_DD_TermCodes.CODE
             AND (SFR1.SFRSTCR_ERROR_FLAG != 'F' OR SFR1.SFRSTCR_ERROR_FLAG IS NULL)
             AND SFR1.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = STV1.STVTERM_CODE
             AND SFR1.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE NOT IN ('DD', 'WC'))
      AND (SFR.SFRSTCR_ERROR_FLAG != 'F' OR SFR.SFRSTCR_ERROR_FLAG IS NULL)
      AND SFR.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE NOT IN ('DD', 'WC')
      AND SFR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSR.SSRMEET_TERM_CODE
      AND SFR.SFRSTCR_CRN = SSR.SSRMEET_CRN
      AND DAY_OF_WEEK.DAY_CODE IN (SSR.SSRMEET_MON_DAY, SSR.SSRMEET_TUE_DAY, SSR.SSRMEET_WED_DAY,
                                  SSR.SSRMEET_THU_DAY, SSR.SSRMEET_FRI_DAY)
      AND SSR.SSRMEET_TERM_CODE = SIR.SIRASGN_TERM_CODE(+)
      AND SSR.SSRMEET_CRN = SIR.SIRASGN_CRN(+)
      AND SSR.SSRMEET_CATAGORY = SIR.SIRASGN_CATEGORY(+)
      AND SIR.SIRASGN_PIDM = SPR_INSTRUCTOR.SPRIDEN_PIDM(+)
      AND SPR_INSTRUCTOR.SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND IS NULL
      AND SFR.SFRSTCR_CRN = SSB.SSBSECT_CRN
      AND SFR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSB.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
      AND SSB.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE = SCB.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE
      AND SSB.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB = SCB.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB
      AND DAY_DESC = :chart_Avail_by_Day.Avail_by_Day.GROUP_DAY_OF_WEEK
      AND (SCB.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE || SCB.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB) NOT LIKE 'ES0%' -- Exclude all "Sport" "classes" (eg. Football, Baseball, etc.)
      AND SCB.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM =
            (SELECT MAX(SCB1.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM)
             FROM SCBCRSE SCB1
             WHERE SCB1.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE = SSB.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE
             AND SCB1.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB = SSB.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB
             AND SCB1.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM <= SFR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE)) ATHL_CRSE_CONF
GROUP BY ATHL_CRSE_CONF.GROUP_DAY_OF_WEEK)
SELECT HOUR_CODE, HOUR_COUNTS
FROM   TEMP_ATH_SCHEDULE
UNPIVOT(
      HOUR_COUNTS
      FOR HOUR_CODE IN (Hour00,Hour01,Hour02,Hour03,Hour04,Hour05,Hour06,Hour07,Hour08,Hour09,Hour10,Hour11,Hour12,Hour13,Hour14,Hour15,Hour16,Hour17,Hour18,Hour19,Hour20,Hour21,Hour22,Hour23)
       )
ORDER BY HOUR_CODE ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is logic, though it needs updated for Oracle and your schedule record.  The idea here is that you are creating a result set including all hours 0-23.  You then evaluate every schedule record with that result set and count the ones where students are not available.

```
;WITH HoursOfDay AS (
SELECT 0 AS HourOfDay
UNION ALL
SELECT HourOfDay + 1 FROM HoursOfDay WHERE HourOfDay + 1 < 24
)

SELECT h.HourOfDay,
    CASE WHEN h.HourOfDay >= DATEPART(HOUR, SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME) AND h.HourOfDay <= SSRMEET_END_TIME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CountUnavailable
FROM HoursOfDay AS h
LEFT JOIN Schedule AS s ON 1 = 1
GROUP BY h.HourOfDay
ORDER BY h.HourOfDay
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE classes (id, start_date, end_date) AS
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 08:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 09:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 07:30:00', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 15:30:00' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE student_appointments (id, student_id, start_date, end_date) AS
SELECT 1, 1, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 08:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 09:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 07:30:00', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 15:30:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 16:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 07:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 07:30:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 4, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 15:30:00', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 5, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 07:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 6, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 12:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 13:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 6, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 14:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 15:00:00' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can count the number of students with conflicting appointments using:

```sql
SELECT c.id AS class_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT s.student_id) AS num_students_unavailable
FROM   classes c
       INNER JOIN student_appointments s
       ON (c.start_date < s.end_date AND s.start_date < c.end_date)
GROUP BY
       c.id;
```

Which outputs:

| CLASS_ID | NUM_STUDENTS_UNAVAILABLE |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tJR3AWiD)